# Automatically assign the same Id for the duplicate value in column

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, phpmyadmin

I have a form that inserts dates into MySql and my table looks like this:

```
id |  date
----------------
1 | 2013-06-01    
2 | 2013-06-01    
3 | 2013-06-01    
4 | 2013-06-02
etc...
```

Basically, with every data entry the id increases (which is fine), but is it possible that if the date is the same , it assign automatically the same,unique  id number?
Like:

```
id |  date
----------------
1 | 2013-06-01    
1 | 2013-06-01    
2 | 2013-06-02    
3 | 2013-06-03    
3 | 2013-06-03
```

Comment: Why would you want to insert an exact duplicate row? This would create a lot of unnecessary rows.

Answer (score 1):

No. It would not be a unique ID anymore.

Comment: Thanx for a quick aswer. Is there some kind of alternative to it?

Comment: If you describe what you're actually trying to do, someone can probably help you.